# SPFX context menu command set extension not showing for picture library

Tags: spfx-extensions, picture-library, context-menu

I am developing a ContextMenu command set for sharepoint online for my tenant. I developed the program and tested and from localhost it was working as expected. When I deployed the extension and installed the extension in my site as it is not tenant wide deployment, the extension appeared for all "Document Library" of the site but its not appearing for "Picture Library".

I am assuming my elements.xml definition may have some issue. Here is xml:

```
<CustomAction
        Title="CopyImage"
        RegistrationId="101"
        RegistrationType="List"
        Location="ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet.ContextMenu"
        ClientSideComponentId="the guid of the extension">
</CustomAction>
```

I am guessing the issue might be "101" and "List". I found a possible value of RegistrationId=109 from [this link](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/4691), tried this one too, but didnt appear and its still appearing in the document libraries.
I would be very greatful if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update ListTemplateId(ListTemplateId="109") of ClientSideInstance.xml to keep the same as elements.xml(RegistrationId="109") and package.

Uninstall and Reinstall is also a crucial step. **And dont forget to change the version of the app**.

Comment: Is the clientSideInstance.xml necessary for NON tenant-wide deployment? In my previous extension development I totally removed ClientSideInstance.xml's reference from package-solution.json and it is still working okay although it was developed targeting document library.

Comment: Ok I did both of the chages, that is updating the ClientSideInstance.xml and reinstall and the extension is now working. Although I think just reinstalling probably would have worked. Thanks a lot for the help.